# Testing Deployed Smart Contract on Truffle

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

Testing Deployed Smart Contract on Truffle

```
Uncaught: Error: Hello has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

Error: Hello has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Function.deployed (C:\Users\m_swe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\contract\constructorMethods.js:83:1)
    at Object.checkNetworkArtifactMatch (C:\Users\m_swe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\utils\index.js:247:1)
truffle(development)>
```

my smart contract is

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;   

contract Hello {
    string private helloMessage = "Hello world";

    function getHelloMessage() public view returns (string memory) {
        return helloMessage;
    }
}
```

I ran migrate command under development and I got below

```
truffle(development)> migrate

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Hello.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Hello.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\m_swe\project\firstproject\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.9+commit.e5eed63a.Emscripten.clang

Network up to date.
```

Comment: What does your migration script look like?

Comment: I'm trying to run smart contract (Solidity) on truffle environment

Comment: What's the content of the deploying scripts?